# Generating / Hiding messages from middleware in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, middleware, django-middleware

I've got a django app that has some middleware (written in the new style) that checks to see if something a user can register for has become 'full' before the user has finished the process to register for it.

If it has become full - the middleware kicks off an error message letting the user know that it's become full and links them to their registration so they can change it.

The middleware looks like this:

```
def __call__(self, request):
    # Code to be executed for each request before
    # the view (and later middleware) are called.
    # ....extra logic (working without issue)....
        full_problem_registrations = Registration.objects.filter(
            id__in=full_problem_registration_ids
        )
        request.full_problem_registrations = full_problem_registrations
        request.session['registration_now_full'] = False
        if full_problem_registrations:
            request.session['registration_now_full'] = True
            for problem_reg in full_problem_registrations:
                reg_url = reverse(
                    "camp_registrations:edit_registration", kwargs={
                            'person_id': problem_reg.person.id,
                            'registration_id': problem_reg.id,
                        }
                    )
                url_string = '<a href="%s">' % reg_url
                error_message = format_html(
                    "The %s %s registration for %s %s at %s</a> has become\
                     full and is no longer available. Please either remove\
                     or change this registration." % (
                        url_string,
                        problem_reg.course_detail.course.camp.name,
                        problem_reg.person.first_name,
                        problem_reg.person.last_name,
                        problem_reg.course_detail.location.name,
                        )
                    )
                existing_messages = get_messages(request)
                if existing_messages:
                    for message in get_messages(request):
                        # check for duplicates
                        if message.message == error_message:
                            pass
                        else:
                            messages.error(
                                request,
                                error_message,
                                )
                else:
                    messages.error(
                        request,
                        error_message,
                        )

    else:
        pass
    response = self.get_response(request)
    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.

    return response
```

This works great - the message is displayed letting everyone know the user has a problem with their registration.

However - when the user goes in to edit their registration and changes to a non-full course and saves it - when they save it redirects them to the next page.

On the next page it shows the success message - but also continues to show the error message. If the user refreshes or goes to any other page on the site, the error message goes away.

This is because the middleware is processing *before* the view is processed - and at that time the error is still true.

What is the best way to fix that and keep it from showing?

I figured in the middleware portion after the view is processed (which I believe would include the processing of the POST data) then we could run the check again and remove the error if it exists; but I can't figure out how to nicely remove an error from the messages.

```
    response = self.get_response(request)
    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.
    # should I be checking here to see if the problem still exists and 
    # removing the message here?
```

I've tried that - but struggle with figuring out how to remove *just that specific message* from the `FallbackStorage` object.

Forms are processed using Class Based Views (in particular this one is an `UpdateView`)

Comment: Why not clear all previous messages when setting the success message in the view?

Comment: In the event 2 or more registrations were a problem (some people might register for multiple classes that might have the issue of becoming full) - I wouldn't want to clear out legitimate concerns. Although, I suppose they would see the error on the next page... so that might be a decent temporary workaround. But I'd like them to see appropriate errors if possible. Also, the form is a CBV UpdateView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to keep running that check on every request and as far I understand the "problem" messages keep interferring with others (like the "success" message) and it's difficult to tell them apart I would recommend to probably not use the messages framework for that, you could eg. just create a simple [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) that provides the data for the full registrations to every template on every request. So these messages won't get persisted into the session but freshly generated on every request.

Something like:

```
# context processor
def registrations(request):
    # .....
    full_problem_registrations = Registration.objects.filter(
        id__in=full_problem_registration_ids
    )
    return full_problem_registrations

# add a snippet to eg. your base template
{% if full_problem_registrations.exists %}
    Generate problem messages here
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Alright, I think this would work. Is there a reason/logic on when to use a context_processor vs. middleware? In an instance like this it seems they do similar things.

Comment: A context processor just adds stuff on every request to every template context. With a middleware you can intercept requests/responses and modify them or do other stuff as well, but if you just want to get some data to your template on every request a context processor is enough. And as you perform your query on every request it's not necessary ton enqueue the messages in the session (which then causes some problems...)

Comment: This worked great. I was able to balance the middleware with session variables to handle some safety on the view side (redirecting people if they try to get to views while registrations are full, etc.) and the context_processor was the perfect solution for the error message on the template side. Thanks!